# If it's possible to set a marker on "meter" tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know if it is possible to set some marker on the "meter" tag in HTML5?

```
      <meter id="signalGreen" min="0"  max="100" value="45"></meter>
```

For example, if I want to set marker when the value will pass 90. 
Thanks.

Comment: You could probably do this with a mutation observer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 0):

You can add class attribute with certain class name for this tag:

```
`<meter class="over-the-range" id="disk_c" value="2" min="0" max="10">2 out of 10</meter>`
```

Then you should use `elem.className` or `elem.classList` methods for changing class attribute like this:

`document.body.classList.add('your-class');`